# How many children should you have in islam

Tags: nikah

How many children should you have in Islam? One two three four or more.

Comment: Salam and Welcome to Islam.SE, we suggest you read the FAQ.  Here we discourage people from asking two questions in one, as well as we discourage questions asking about a specific region.  we recommend you look around this site to see how things work, and again we welcome you :)

Answer (score 3):

There is no limit on the children we can have, whatever Allah blesses us with we thank Him.  We are encouraged to get married to a wife who is willing to have many children (usually a women who herself was in a big family), and discouraged to getting married to one who cannot bear any children.  It has been [narrated](http://sunnah.com/nasai/26/32) that the Prophet (peace and blessings be upon him) said when a man came to him asking whether he should marry a women who cannot bear children, the man asked three times and the Prophet each time said no, on the third he said:

> تَزَوَّجُوا الْوَلُودَ الْوَدُودَ فَإِنِّي مُكَاثِرٌ بِكُمْ
>
> Marry the one who is fertile and loving, for I will boast of your
>   great numbers

Sources: Islamic online university

Comment: I guess there is a hadith which explicitly commands to have as more children as possible?

Answer (score 1):

The "count" should be as many as you can provide for them to have a good live, future, education,... and raise as good persons to themselves and to others.